# (.htaccess) Denying access to folder unless linked to from specific pages?

Tags: apache, web-services, .htaccess

I'm trying to deny access to all files within (and indexing of) a directory on my website unless a link has been provided from a specific set of pages. I'm trying to get this to work via a .htaccess file that sits in the protected directory, but I can't get it to work.

My current .htaccess file reads:

```
 Options -Indexes
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www.mywebsite.com/downloads/* [NC]
 RewriteRule \.*$ - [F,NC]
```

In this case I want to deny access to all files/folders unless linked to from the 'downloads' page or any of it's sub pages (i.e 'downloads/page1' would be valid).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

As long as your htaccess file is in the directory you want to limit access to, your regex should probably look more like:

```
 Options -Indexes
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www\.mywebsite\.com/downloads/ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still allows me to access the files from anywhere if I type the full URL to the files in the address bar, is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @MichaelHillman then get rid of the first condition. It you type the full URL in the address bar, the referer is blank, thus you don't want to let this condition bypass the rule: ` RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work,  I can't access the files with the full URLS (correctly), but when linked to a file from the mywebsite.com/downloads page, I get permissions errors.